# How to get value on a single row with XPath?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xpath, sql-server-2012

I have a user table, email table and a relational email table. Some users have more than one email addresses. 
When Use

```
select U.Id,U.Name,E.Name from RelationalEmail AS RE
INNER JOIN Email AS E ON E.Id = RE.EmailId
INNER JOIN User AS U ON U.Id=RE.userId
```

Of course, I get the result like this:

```
UserId    Name     Email
1         Olcay    abc@.com
1         Olcay    acc@.com
2         John     jhn@.com
2         John     hnJ@.com
```

But I don't want repeat of users,
 I try to get a result like:

```
UserId    Name     Email      
1         Olcay    abc@.com, acc@.com
2         John     jhn@.com, hnJ@.com
```

My Person Table:

```
  UserId    Name      
    1         Olcay    
    2         John
```

My Email Table:

```
EmailId    Name
   7         abc@.com
   8         acc@.com
   9         jhn@.com
   10        hnJ@.com
```

My RelationalEmail Table:

```
Id   userId  EmailId
  1      1     7
  2      1     8
  3      2     9
  4      2     10
```

My teacher said I should do that with XPath. But I don't know XPath. I searched that but I couldn't find an answer for my question or I couldn't understand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server) answer.

Comment: Share more details. Currently I don't see how this issue is related to `XPath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is always two `emails` per `name`, then here is one way

```
select UserId, 
       Name, 
       Email = Min(Email),
       Email2 = Max(Email)
From yourtable 
Group by UserId, 
         Name
```

If you can have `N` number of `emails` per `name` then you need `dynamic pivot`.